# WinRT BitmapIcon Alpha Bug

Tags: image, windows-runtime, alpha

Can anyone explain what is going on with the **BitmapIcon** in WinRT?  As I understand it, and the documentation is sparse, the **BitmapIcon** basically strips the color information out of an image and allows you to replace it with a Foreground color.  However, if you create an image with white pixels and load it up in an **BitmapIcon** and set the foreground color to a "White" brush, it appears to corrupt the *alpha* values.  My images use pure white pixels with the *alpha* used to provide rounding touches against a dark background.  Here's what it looks like when loaded using an **Image** control:

[image]

Here's what the same PNG file looks like when loaded up using a **BitmapIcon** and setting the Foreground to "White":

[image]

The *alpha* information is completely lost.  All the pixels are set to 0xFFFFFF regardless of the *alpha* value in the original image.  Now here's where it gets a little strange.  If I use a "Black" Foreground color, I get:

[image]

For some reason, the *alpha* shows up in some form on the darker images.  Instead of taking the *alpha* literally from the original PNG image, there seems to be some function related to the foreground brush being applied.  Can anyone give some insight into how the *alpha* component works (or doesn't work) on the **BitmapIcon** element?

Comment: Can you share your image file?

Comment: I wonder if it might have something to do with the premultiplied vs. non-premultiplied alpha pixel format in the file. Have you tried using an image with black icon pixels instead of white ones?

Comment: If you have a suggestion on how I can share the image file, I'd give it a try.  As far as using black pixels, same effect as you see above.  When the Foreground is set to White, all pixels that have alpha values show up as 0xFFFFFF.

Comment: Hmmm, no idea then. I'd try hitting msdn forums - maybe someone might help you there.

Comment: Do you have a vector graphic of that icon? You could use `PathIcon` instead.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the issue.  The effective space for the image inside an AppBarButton is about 24x24.  The only way to achieve a professional looking, monochrome image is using the alpha to round the images.  There is no possible way to use a PathIcon to produce the type of images displayed above in the given space.

Comment: DRAirey1, did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with AppBarButton and a white/transparent image.

The following sentence from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.iconelement.foreground the first part of your post:

> "Foreground replaces the color information from a BitmapIcon.UriSource
>   source file. Any non-transparent pixel in the source image is replaced
>   with the Foreground color."

I agree with you it's an annoying behaviour if you prepare the image correctly. And why it works for dark foreground colors I don't know.

Finally I wrote my own control:

```
public class Primitive3StateImagesButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource",
        typeof (ImageSource), typeof (Primitive3StateImagesButton), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointerOverImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PointerOverImageSource", typeof (ImageSource),
        typeof (Primitive3StateImagesButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PressedImageSource",
        typeof (ImageSource), typeof (Primitive3StateImagesButton), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Primitive3StateImagesButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof (Primitive3StateImagesButton);
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return ((ImageSource) (GetValue(ImageSourceProperty))); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource PointerOverImageSource
    {
        get { return ((ImageSource) (GetValue(PointerOverImageSourceProperty))); }
        set { SetValue(PointerOverImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource PressedImageSource
    {
        get { return ((ImageSource) (GetValue(PressedImageSourceProperty))); }
        set { SetValue(PressedImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

With style:

```
  <Style TargetType="ctrls:Primitive3StateImagesButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource 
        AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource 
        ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrls:Primitive3StateImagesButton">
          <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="RootGrid">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                          Value="{ThemeResource 
                          AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                          Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                          Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid
              Height="30"
              Width="30">
              <Ellipse
                x:Name="Ellipse"
                Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                Stroke="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                UseLayoutRounding="False" />
              <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Width="18" Height="18" Visibility="Visible" />
              <Image x:Name="PointerOverImage" 
                  Source="{TemplateBinding PointerOverImageSource}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Width="18" Height="18" Visibility="Collapsed" />
              <Image x:Name="PressedImage" 
                  Source="{TemplateBinding PressedImageSource}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Width="18" Height="18" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" 
                Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                StrokeDashArray="1,1" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" 
                Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                StrokeDashArray="1,1" />
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```